# Negative dates in sqllite database

Tags: sqlite, date

I am working locally with an `sqllite` DB. I have imported some records from `teradata` where there was a date field in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'. When i imported the records the date switched from a date to a number. I know this is a feature of `sqllite` and that one can access it via `date(sqllite_date)` when selecting it in a where clause.

My problem is that the dates now appear to be a bit odd. For example the year appears to be negative.
Is there anyway to recover this to the correct format?
Below is an example of converting a number in the database into a date

```sql
SELECT date(18386)
# -4662-03-28

SELECT datetime('now')
# 2021-02-11 10:41:52

SELECT date(sqllite_date) FROM mydb
# Returns -4662-03-28
# Should return 2020-05-04
```

I am very new to this area so apologies if this is a basic question. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite you can store dates as `TEXT`, `REAL` or `INTEGER`.
It seems that you stored the dates in a column with `INTEGER` or `REAL` affinity.
In this case, if you use the function `date()`, it considers a value like `18386` as a [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), meaning the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C.
This is why `date(18386)` returns `4662-03-28`B.C.

But I suspect that the date values that you have are the number of days since `'1970-01-01'`.
In this case, `18386` days after `'1970-01-01'` is `'2020-05-04'`.

So you can get the dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` if you add the value of your column as days to `'1970-01-01'`:

```
SELECT date('1970-01-01', datecolumn || ' day') FROM tablename
```

Or by transforming your date values to seconds and treat them as UNIX time (the number of seconds since `'1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'`):

```
SELECT date(datecolumn * 24 * 3600, 'unixepoch') FROM tablename
```

Replace `datecolumn` with the name of your column.